# Bluetooth with Python and Arduino (HC-06)

Tags: python, c, bluetooth, arduino

I'm trying to send information from my Arduino to Python. The information I'm sending is a string of 16 characters and the problem is I'm not receiving all the data at once.

Arduino code:

```
void setup(){
  BTserial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  BTserial.print("0123456789012345");
  delay(500);
}
```

Python code:

```
import bluetooth

sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect(("00:13:04:83:EC:45", 1))

while(True):
   print(sock.recv(10))
```

The output that comes out is:

```
b'0'
b'123456789'
b'012345'
```

The output that I want is:

```
b'0123456789012345'
```

or

```
0123456789012345
```

Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have temporary really massy way to fix it but if this is possible any other way let me know

```
string = ""
final = ""
num = 0

while(True):
   string = sock.recv(4096)
   if str(string) == "b'$'":
      num=1
   elif num == 1:
      final+=str(string)
      num = 2
   elif num == 2:
      final += str(string)
      final = final.replace(("b"), "")
      final = final.replace(("'"), "")
      print(final)
      final = ""
      num == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Append a message delimiter character to the arduino output sequence; your choice but ‘\n’ would be good. Make a python generator function that reads input characters from bluetooth stream, assembling them into a buffer. Yield the entire buffer when the message delimiter character has been received, so the function calling the generator blocks until the entire message is available.